# Device to squeeze last yogurt out of carton

Tags: equipment, yogurt

When you have a viscous liquid like yogurt in a tetra pak carton it is difficult to get the last of it out. What is the name of press which can be used to flatten the carton and squeeze out the full contents?

Comment: There is a tool?

Comment: Uhm...."Hands"?

Comment: Cut off top, use rubber spatula?

Comment: Are we talking about the boxy aspetic packaging?  If so, there should be two little ears on the bottom of the package.  Pry them loose and flip them up and it becomes more like a toothpaste tube.  With the carton above the counter (and maybe over a plate to catch), press the bottom seam against the sharp edge of the counter, then push/pull down while keeping some force against the counter edge (even flexing it around the edge).  This will move everything up to the top of the container, and you can get more out.  You might also be able to put it through a pasta roller, but it would be messy.

Comment: To add to the @Joe comment, you could use a rolling pin to press down and roll the remaining product to the top of the container.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips. I will add that I have seen this device before made out of plastic, but I have been unable to find anything similar searching online.

Comment: I guess cutting the corners with a utility knife, laying the whole carton out flat, and using a bench scraper would be the be all end all in harvesting as much yoghurt as you can :)

Comment: @rackandboneman : agreed, and stress the utility knife -- paper dulls knives, so don't use a good kitchen knife for this task.

Comment: Always implying "knife for the naughty tasks" - cutting packaging, scraping things, settling kitchen disputes - when saying "utility" :)

Answer (score 1):

As the response to my comment didn't say it *wasn't* the boxy aseptic packaging (used for soy/rice/coconut/almond milk, broth/stocks, shelf-stable milk, milk and juice cartons, etc.), I'm going to assume it was, and move it to an answer:

Square or rectangular packaging should have two little ears on the bottom of the package.  If you pry them up, you'll find that the box is really a tube with one end sealed, like a tube of toothpaste.

I've not tried this for the aseptic packaging (as I've never gotten viscous items packaged that way), but you might be able to use the same trick for toothpaste tube:

1. With the open container on the top of the counter, press the sealed edge on a sharp corner of the counter (not one of those really rounded over ones, as those don't work as well).
2. Place your hand on top of the container, and push it both down and off the edge of the counter.
3. Once you have enough over the edge to grab, grip it and pull it down (or at least at a downward angle).  This will force the contents towards the open end of the tube.
4. Once the contents come up to the container's opening, squeeze in into a bowl or other vessel.  (it can help to fold the tube a bit, so that squeezing doesn't force it back into the end that you just cleared out).
5. Repeat until you've gotten all that you can out.

It might seem strange, but once you've gotten the hang of it, if you have a good edge to work it against, it's quite easy.  If you don't have a good edge ... you might try against the rim of a sheet pan.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "boxy aseptic packaging", but the OP specified that they are using tetra pak. As far as I can tell that's what your answer is about, too.

Comment: @rumtscho : 'Tetra Pak' is a brand that makes aseptic packaging.  (it's like Kleenex, Xerox, etc, in which a brand name can come to be used for the whole category  (In this case for [cartons made of plastic coated paper, that is filled while hot and immediately sealed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetra_Pak#Aseptic_technology)).  But it's not universal for all places ... 'Clingwrap' vs. 'Saranwrap'; 'Crockpot' vs. 'Slo Cooker'.  And the US doesn't use 'Hoover')  It's available in lots of different shapes (Tetra Brik and Tetra Rex are ones that I'd consider 'boxy', likely others)

Comment: I knew it was brand-derived, but wasn't aware about its lack of universality, so to me it seemed like you had missed the "tetra pak" mention in the question and was trying to find out if you and the OP are thinking about the same thing. Thanks for the clarification!